# Expand page to use full page height with fancyhdr

Tags: floats, fancyhdr, geometry

I use `fancyhdr` package and would like to print a large float that exceeds the textheight. Hence I would like to remove the headers and footers. And have the float verticaly centered. 
I tried

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\enlargethispage{10\baselineskip}
\newgeometry{left=3cm,left=3cm,bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm}
{
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=.7\textwidth,angle=90]{tables/tab_results.pdf}
    \label{tab:results}%
    \captionof{table}{Result table.}%
    \label{tab:ana-res}%
\end{figure}
}
\restoregeometry
```

But the float does not get lower than the (invisible) footrule.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do not forget to replace `[!htbp] ` by `[!p]` otherwise, it will get placed as a top float.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to replace [!htbp] by [!p] otherwise, it will get placed as a top float. Cheers!